# Ruby On Rails - XML-RPC

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to implement a ruby on rails project using XML-RPC. I have no idea where to get started but I've used ruby on rails before (just never with XML-RPC). Can someone help me out on get started with this?

Comment: Did you Google?
http://www.google.com/search?q=xml-rpc+ruby

Comment: There's some related information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541768/providing-an-xml-rpc-service-from-a-ruby-on-rails-application (not a dupe, since that question is about serving normal rails and xmlrpc at the same time, but this one is about just  xmlrpc)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use rails project like a server try this gem: [rails-xmlrpc](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-xmlrpc)

If you want your project to connect to xmlrpc server, here is an example:

```
  require 'xmlrpc/client'
  server = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://localhost:3000/api/xmlrpc")
  server.call("Namespace.method_name")
```

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer, but FFR, it's good form to point out if it's your gem you're linking to

Comment: This gem is great, it was working great until yesterday, today I'm getting a Wrong type NilClass. Not allowed! error.  any ideas?